# Group Layers Do Not Display in GeoExt LegendPanel

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript

I have a GeoExt.LegendPanel which is working just fine for layers which are not grouped.  However, the grouped layers do not show any icon in the LegendPanel.  I have tried to create the group layer various ways, using the exact name of the layer group in Geoserver and aldo by specifying a layer string in code.  I've been looking around for a while now, but I don't see what I am missing..

Here is relevant code:

```
//Layer Group
var geography2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "Geography2", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'cite:geog_multipol_vw,cite:geog_multiline_vw', transparent: true}, {isBaseLayer: false, displayInLayerSwitcher: true, visibility: true, minScale: 27734017.045258757}
               );

//LegendPanel config
var legend = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
                region: "east",
                title: "Legend",
                width: 200,
                autoScroll: true,
                layerStore: mapPanel.layers
            });

//Explicitly point LegendPanel to GetLegendGraphic on WMS Geoserver for GeoWebCached Layers
            var LayerRec;
            for(var l = 4; l < map.layers.length; l++)
            {
                LayerRec = mapPanel.layers.getAt(l);
                LayerRec.set("legendURL","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?TRANSPARENT=true&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&FORMAT=image%2Fgif&LAYER=" + map.layers[l].params["LAYERS"]);
        }
```

Thanks for your time in trying to help me :),

elshae

Comment: You post this questions a while ago. Did you find a solution for your problem? I found your post because I'm looking for a solution to a similar problem. Anyway, in your code, you start at checking the layers from index 4. I was wondering if it was I typo, or something related to the part of the code that we don't see.

Answer (score 1):

do the legend graphics work when you request them directly in the browser? If so there is a problem with the way you are adding them to the legend panel, if not then there is a problem with GeoServer and you need to file a bug report.